# Como separar string em array?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma coluna `descri_produto` que seria a descrição do produto.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo separar a descrição em array.

```
$cat = $_POST['categoria'];
$sql= "SELECT DISTINCT descri_produto, cat_produto FROM produtos WHERE cat_produto  LIKE '".$cat."'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        print_r(explode(',',$row['descri_produto']));
    }
}
```

Linha exemplo da coluna descri_produto

```
Espessura: 6mm,Cor: Incolor
```

No momento está retornando:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Espessura: 6mm
    [1] => Cor: Incolor 
)
```

e eu preciso de algo do tipo:

```
Array
(
    [Espessura] =>  6mm
    [Cor] => Incolor 
)
```

Comment: Você pode jogar em outro array a posição 0 como chave e a posição 1 como valor. `$arr1 = explode(',',$row['descri_produto']);` e depois `$arr2 = array($arr1[0]=>$arr1[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce tem quebrar em 2 partes, primeiro quebrar cada campo, como você esta fazendo, depois quebrar cada campo em chave / valor e colocar num array. criei uma função que faz isso, basta passar o texto que vem do MySQL e ele te retorna o array no formato que você precisa.

```php
function quebra($descricao) {
    $campos = explode(',', $descricao);

    $array = [];

    foreach ($campos as $campo) {
        // o terceiro parametro do explode eh o numero maximo de valores
        // que o explode vai quebrar (2), se por acaso tiver no seu valor outro ':'
        list($chave, $valor) = explode(':', $campo, 2);

        // remove espacos extras
        $chave = trim($chave);
        $valor = trim($valor);

        $array[$chave] = $valor;
    }

    return $array;
}


$quebrado = quebra('Espessura: 6mm,Cor: Incolor');
var_dump($quebrado);
```

Esse código vai imprimir:

```
array(2) {
     ["Espessura"]=> string(3) "6mm"
     ["Cor"]=>  string(7) "Incolor"
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu tudo certinho

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$cat    = $_POST['categoria'];
$sql    = "SELECT DISTINCT descri_produto, cat_produto FROM produtos WHERE 
cat_produto  LIKE '".$cat."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$data   = [];

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $_items = explode(',',$row['descri_produto']);
        foreach ( $_items as $item ) {
            $_data = explode(':', $item);
            $data[strtolower($_data[0])] = $_data[1];
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
die;

// Retorno do data
Array
(
    [espessura] =>  6mm
    [cor] =>  Incolor
)
```

Comment: Obrigado deu tudo certinho